# I can’t use mobile network in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I can’t Connect Web datas when mobile network is öpen. I getted network state, internet and WiFi state. But I can’t use mobile network in volley,

How can I resolve this?

I need your help.

Comment: Need more details about it. What have you tried so far? Any code samples that you implemented? Error logs? Stack traces?

Comment: I would use mobile network in volley. Can you send an example please.@Shankha057

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) is some resource for you.

Comment: @Shankha057 the link is so complicated. Can you make s basic example for me please. I think the problem is in the requestqueue but I don’t understand instance.

Comment: @Shankha057 the link

Comment: Part of learning and growing up, especially as a software developer/engineer is about learning how to read documentations, and patience to shift through tutorials and training materials. Also, your question is hugely lacking in content in terms of problem explanation, your own effort in solving it and your perspective about the solution that you implemented. If you manage to provide all of these, you will get better quality answers with proper explanations in general and catered to your particular mistakes as well